# How to get all child targets

Tags: stimulusjs

My question is how to get all nested controllers data-target values?

---

**Example:**

Event has multiple tasks. So, I have *Event* and *Task* controller. 
I want to get content values from tasks to Event controller.

Tried something like this:

`const nodes = this.data.element.childNodes`

Or `this.contentTarget.dataset`

In Task view I have:

`data-target="task.content event.content"`

So, there is one instance of Event controller, and n of Task controllers. How to get all task titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all the nodes tagged with `data-target="event.content"`, you don't need to deal with the Task controllers at all, you can just reference them in the EventController as

```
class EventController {
  static targets = ["content", ...];

  doSomething() {
    const targets = this.contentTargets;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: So easy, but I didn't know. Thanks @rewritten. I just iterate targets and got innerText